# How to send an email with a calendar request (content type: text/calendar)

Tags: delphi, indy10

I have tried to embed the icalendar code in a email to be sent via indy with a content type text/calendar but it just hangs on the encoding of the email when I add as an attachment it just arrives as an attachment and does not prompt as other calendar request do. Has any one got example code of how to do calendar requests via indy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an alternative to RRUZ's example:

```
program SendMailWithCalendarRequest; 
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE} 

uses 
  IdSMTP, 
  Classes, 
  DateUtils, 
  IdMessage, 
  SysUtils; 

 procedure SendCalendarRequest; 
 var 
  SMTP        : TIdSMTP; 
  MailMessage : TIdMessage; 
 begin 
   SMTP:= TIdSMTP.Create(nil); 
   MailMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil); 
   try 
     SMTP.Host := 'smtp.mailserver.com'; 
     SMTP.Port := 25; 
     SMTP.Username := 'the account'; 
     SMTP.Password := 'the password'; 
     SMTP.AuthType := satDefault; 
     MailMessage.From.Address := 'mail@server.com'; 
     MailMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'the Recipient'; 
     MailMessage.Subject := 'Send calendar'; 
     MailMessage.Body.Add('BEGIN:VCALENDAR'); 
     MailMessage.Body.Add('VERSION:1.0'); 
     MailMessage.Body.Add('BEGIN:VEVENT'); 
     MailMessage.Body.Add('ORGANIZER:MAILTO:'+SenderMail); 
     MailMessage.Body.Add('DTStart:'+FormatDateTime('YYYY-DD-DD',Now)); 
     MailMessage.Body.Add('DTEnd:'+FormatDateTime('YYYY-DD-DD',  Tomorrow)); 
     MailMessage.Body.Add('Location;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE: My home'); 
     MailMessage.Body.Add('UID:'+FormatDateTime('YYYY-DD-DD',Now)+FormatDateTime('YYYY-DD-DD', Tomorrow)); 
     MailMessage.Body.Add('SUMMARY:Appointment Reminder'); 
     MailMessage.Body.Add('DESCRIPTION:Test message'); 
     MailMessage.Body.Add('PRIORITY:5'); 
     MailMessage.Body.Add('END:VEVENT'); 
     MailMessage.Body.Add('END:VCALENDAR'); 
     MailMessage.ContentType := 'text/calendar';
     SMTP.Connect; 
     try 
       try 
         SMTP.Send(MailMessage) ; 
         Writeln('OK') 
       except on E:Exception do 
         Writeln(0, 'ERROR: ' + E.Message) ; 
       end; 
     finally 
       SMTP.Disconnect; 
     end; 
   finally 
    SMTP.Free; 
    MailMessage.Free; 
   end; 
 end; 

begin 
  try 
    SendCalendarRequest; 
    readln; 
  except 
    on E: Exception do 
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message); 
  end; 
end.
```

Comment: Thanks, I ran RRUZ program kind of worked in gmail, but outlook when retrieving the email just terminates.  
More specific. The service auto sends email from the server using Indy each email has a text/plain part, the text/html part and optionally attachments. This works fine. When trying to incorporate the ical on the end similar to example with content text/calendar; method=request as a final part the program freezes after encoding message for the first parts but a problem on the calendar part.
The message part as if a text/plain with the tstrings of the ical and the content as mentioned.

Comment: Then you are likely not filling in the TIdMessage correctly, please show your actual code.

Comment: my code below, added part is the last after attachments ect

Procedure Emailer.BuildCalendar(Msg_In : TIdMessage); 
var s: TStrings;
const  TAB  = #9;
begin
   try s:= TStringList.Create;
   s.Add('BEGIN:VCALENDAR');
... other lines added here .....
   s.Add('END:VCALENDAR');
   // Create the Calendar parts
   with TIdText.Create(Msg_In.MessageParts, s) do
   begin                   
      ContentType := 'text/calendar; method="REQUEST"; charset="UTF-8"';
      ParentPart := 0 ; // IdText.CharSet
   end;

   finally s.free; end;
end;
.... with thanks

Comment: You did not show your entire TIdMessage code.  However, you are setting ParentPart:=0, which is putting the attachment at the wrong level of the message.  ParentPart is used for nesting, and the attachment should not be nested.  Leave ParentPart set to -1.

Comment: That was it. Changed ParentPart and now works ok. How embarrassing. Thanks very much for all your assistance. Regards David

Answer (score 5):

@David, the email client will recognize as a calendar request the attachment if you set the property to `ContentType:='text/calendar'`, see this link for the [iCalendar format Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545)

see this sample code (tested en Delphi 2010)

```
program SendMailWithCalendarRequest;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}


uses
  IdSMTP,
  Classes,
  DateUtils,
  IdAttachmentFile,
  IdMessage,
  SysUtils;

 procedure SendCalendarRequest;
 var
  SMTP        : TIdSMTP;
  MailMessage : TIdMessage;
  Calendar    : TStrings;
  CalendarFile: String;
  Attachment  : TIdAttachmentFile;
  SenderMail  : String;
 begin
    SenderMail:='mail@server.com';
    CalendarFile:=ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'\appmnt.vcs';
    Calendar:=TStringList.Create;
    try
        Calendar.Add('BEGIN:VCALENDAR');
        Calendar.Add('VERSION:1.0');
        Calendar.Add('BEGIN:VEVENT');
        Calendar.Add('ORGANIZER:MAILTO:'+SenderMail);
        Calendar.Add('DTStart:'+FormatDateTime('YYYY-DD-DD',Now));
        Calendar.Add('DTEnd:'+FormatDateTime('YYYY-DD-DD',  Tomorrow));
        Calendar.Add('Location;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE: My home');
        Calendar.Add('UID:'+FormatDateTime('YYYY-DD-DD',Now)+FormatDateTime('YYYY-DD-DD',Tomorrow));
        Calendar.Add('SUMMARY:Appointment Reminder');
        Calendar.Add('DESCRIPTION:Test message');
        Calendar.Add('PRIORITY:5');
        Calendar.Add('END:VEVENT');
        Calendar.Add('END:VCALENDAR');
        Calendar.SaveToFile(CalendarFile);
    finally
    Calendar.Free;
    end;

   SMTP:= TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
   MailMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
   try
     SMTP.Host := 'smtp.mailserver.com';
     SMTP.Port := 25;
     SMTP.Username:='the account';
     SMTP.Password:='the password';
     SMTP.AuthType:=satDefault;
     MailMessage.From.Address := SenderMail;
     MailMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'the Recipient';
     MailMessage.Subject   := 'Send calendar';
     MailMessage.Body.Text := '';
     Attachment:=TIdAttachmentFile.Create(MailMessage.MessageParts, CalendarFile) ;
     Attachment.ContentType:='text/calendar';//set the content type to text/calendar
     try
       try
         SMTP.Connect;
         SMTP.Send(MailMessage) ;
         Writeln('OK')
       except on E:Exception do
         Writeln(0, 'ERROR: ' + E.Message) ;
       end;
     finally
       if SMTP.Connected then SMTP.Disconnect;
     end;
   finally
    SMTP.Free;
    MailMessage.Free;
   end;

 end;

begin
  try
    SendCalendarRequest;
    readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```